# How do I put two forcefields in the same LAMMPS code?

Tags: lammps, forcefields

I need to put two interactions of `ffields` in the same code, but, I don't know what is the problem with the way I tried it. The code shows me `ERROR 309` (see below), however I tried everything and it didn't work.

```
**error:** LAMMPS (9 Oct 2020)
OMP_NUM_THREADS environment is not set. Defaulting to 1 thread. 
(src/comm.cpp:94) using 1 OpenMP thread(s) per MPI task
Reading data file ... orthogonal box = (0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000) to (79.999989 79.999989 79.999989)
1 by 1 by 1 MPI processor grid
reading atoms ... 1352 atoms
read_data CPU = 0.003 seconds
WARNING: Changed valency_val to valency_boc for X (src/USER-REAXC/reaxc_ffield.cpp:315)
ERROR: Incorrect args for pair coefficients (src/USER-REAXC/pair_reaxc.cpp:309)
Last command: pair_coeff * * ffield_Co_Li_O.reax.txt Co O
```

**SIMULATION:**

```
#Inicializacão---------------------------------------------
units           real
dimension       3
boundary        p p p
atom_style      charge

#Posições iniciais dos atomos---------------------------
read_data       Pd_Co_O.txt

#Potencial-----------------------
pair_style      reax/c NULL
pair_coeff      1 2 ffield_Pd_O_C_H.ajust.reax.txt Pd O NULL
pair_coeff      1 3 ffield_Co_Li_O.reax.txt Co O


#Minimização-----------------------
neighbor        0.3 bin
neigh_modify    every 10 delay 0 check no
velocity        all create 333.15 300288 dist gaussian mom yes rot yes


#Computando valores----------------------------------------------
compute  reax  all pair reax/c
variable eb    equal c_reax[1]
variable ea    equal c_reax[2]
variable elp   equal c_reax[3]
variable emol  equal c_reax[4]
variable ev    equal c_reax[5]
variable epen  equal c_reax[6]
variable ecoa  equal c_reax[7]
variable ehb   equal c_reax[8]
variable et    equal c_reax[9]
variable eco   equal c_reax[10]
variable ew    equal c_reax[11]
variable ep    equal c_reax[12]
variable efi   equal c_reax[13]
variable eqeq  equal c_reax[14]


#Definindo grupos de atomos-----------------------------------------
group          paladio  type    1
group          cobalto  type    2
group        oxigenio   type    3


#Fix---------------------------------------------------------
reset_timestep 0
timestep       0.2
fix            1 all nve
fix            2 all qeq/reax 1 0.0 10.0 1.0e-6 reax/c
fix            3 all temp/berendsen 333.15 333.15 10.0

#Resultados------------------------------------------------------

thermo         100
thermo_style   custom step temp epair etotal press v_eb v_ea v_elp v_emol v_ev v_epen v_ecoa v_ehb v_et v_eco v_ew v_ep v_efi v_eqeq
fix            4 oxigenio reax/c/species 1 10 100 species_coh.out element Pd Co O
dump           5 all custom 100 dump.reaxc id type x y z


run            1000
write_data     sistema_final_pdcoo.data 

print          "Fim da Simulação"
```

**CODE FFIELD 1:**

```
Reactive MD-force field: Pd/O/C/H
 39 ! Number of general parameters
 50.0000 !Overcoordination parameter
 9.5469 !Overcoordination parameter
 26.5405 !Valency angle conjugation parameter
 1.7224 !Triple bond stabilisation parameter
 6.8702 !Triple bond stabilisation parameter
 60.4850 !C2-correction
 1.0588 !Undercoordination parameter
 4.6000 !Triple bond stabilisation parameter
 12.1176 !Undercoordination parameter
 13.3056 !Undercoordination parameter
 -70.5044 !Triple bond stabilization energy
 0.0000 !Lower Taper-radius
 10.0000 !Upper Taper-radius
 2.8793 !Not used
 33.8667 !Valency undercoordination
 6.0891 !Valency angle/lone pair parameter
 1.0563 !Valency angle
 2.0384 !Valency angle parameter
 6.1431 !Not used
 6.9290 !Double bond/angle parameter
 0.3989 !Double bond/angle parameter: overcoord
 3.9954 !Double bond/angle parameter: overcoord
 -2.4837 !Not used
 5.7796 !Torsion/BO parameter
 10.0000 !Torsion overcoordination
 1.9487 !Torsion overcoordination
 -1.2327 !Conjugation 0 (not used)
 2.1645 !Conjugation
 1.5591 !vdWaals shielding
 0.1000 !Cutoff for bond order (*100)
 2.1365 !Valency angle conjugation parameter
 0.6991 !Overcoordination parameter
 50.0000 !Overcoordination parameter
 1.8512 !Valency/lone pair parameter
 0.5000 !Not used
 20.0000 !Not used
 5.0000 !Molecular energy (not used)
 0.0000 !Molecular energy (not used)
 2.6962 !Valency angle conjugation parameter
 5 ! Nr of atoms; cov.r; valency;a.m;Rvdw;Evdw;gammaEEM;cov.r2;#
 alfa;gammavdW;valency;Eunder;Eover;chiEEM;etaEEM;n.u.
 cov r3;Elp;Heat inc.;n.u.;n.u.;n.u.;n.u.
 ov/un;val1;n.u.;val3,vval4
 C 1.3817 4.0000 12.0000 1.8903 0.1838 0.9000 1.1341 4.0000
 9.7559 2.1346 4.0000 34.9350 79.5548 5.9666 7.0000 0.0000
 1.2114 0.0000 202.5551 8.9539 34.9289 13.5366 0.8563 0.0000
 -2.8983 2.5000 1.0564 4.0000 2.9663 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 
 H 0.8930 1.0000 1.0080 1.3550 0.0930 0.8203 -0.1000 1.0000
 8.2230 33.2894 1.0000 0.0000 121.1250 3.7248 9.6093 1.0000
 -0.1000 0.0000 61.6606 3.0408 2.4197 0.0003 1.0698 0.0000
 -19.4571 4.2733 1.0338 1.0000 2.8793 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
 O 1.2450 2.0000 15.9990 2.3890 0.1000 1.0898 1.0548 6.0000
 9.7300 13.8449 4.0000 37.5000 116.0768 8.5000 8.3122 2.0000
 0.9049 0.4056 59.0626 3.5027 0.7640 0.0021 0.9745 0.0000
 -3.5500 2.9000 1.0493 4.0000 2.9225 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
 X -0.1000 2.0000 1.0080 2.0000 0.0000 1.0000 -0.1000 6.0000
 10.0000 2.5000 4.0000 0.0000 0.0000 3.5000 85.0000 0.0000
 -0.1000 0.0000 -2.3700 8.7410 13.3640 0.6690 0.9745 0.0000
 -11.0000 2.7466 1.0338 6.2998 2.8793 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
 Pd 1.8582 2.0000 106.4200 2.0113 0.2465 1.0000 -1.0000 2.0000
 12.5712 6.0083 2.0000 0.0000 0.0000 5.5005 6.6477 0.0000
 -1.0000 0.0000 89.8000 27.2704 1.8727 0.1586 0.8563 0.0000
 -13.0000 1.7287 1.0338 5.0000 2.5791 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
 10 ! Nr of bonds; Edis1;LPpen;n.u.;pbe1;pbo5;13corr;pbo6
 pbe2;pbo3;pbo4;n.u.;pbo1;pbo2;ovcorr
 1 1 158.2004 99.1897 78.0000 -0.7738 -0.4550 1.0000 37.6117 0.4147
 0.4590 -0.1000 9.1628 1.0000 -0.0777 6.7268 1.0000 0.0000
 1 2 169.4760 0.0000 0.0000 -0.6083 0.0000 1.0000 6.0000 0.7652
 5.2290 1.0000 0.0000 1.0000 -0.0500 6.9136 0.0000 0.0000
 2 2 153.3934 0.0000 0.0000 -0.4600 0.0000 1.0000 6.0000 0.7300
 6.2500 1.0000 0.0000 1.0000 -0.0790 6.0552 0.0000 0.0000
 1 3 158.6946 107.4583 23.3136 -0.4240 -0.1743 1.0000 10.8209 1.0000
 0.5322 -0.3113 7.0000 1.0000 -0.1447 5.2450 0.0000 0.0000
 3 3 142.2858 145.0000 50.8293 0.2506 -0.1000 1.0000 29.7503 0.6051
 0.3451 -0.1055 9.0000 1.0000 -0.1225 5.5000 1.0000 0.0000 
 2 3 160.0000 0.0000 0.0000 -0.5725 0.0000 1.0000 6.0000 0.5626
 1.1150 1.0000 0.0000 0.0000 -0.0920 4.2790 0.0000 0.0000
 1 5 195.8048 0.0000 0.0000 -0.2150 -0.2000 1.0000 16.0000 0.1001
 10.7579 -0.2000 15.0000 1.0000 -0.1606 4.0000 1.0000 0.0000
 2 5 67.5406 0.0000 0.0000 0.6327 0.0000 1.0000 6.0000 0.2077
 0.7493 1.0000 0.0000 1.0000 -0.0547 4.0000 0.0000 0.0000
 3 5 56.7412 0.0000 0.0000 0.7149 -0.2000 1.0000 16.0000 0.1000
 11.9839 -0.2000 15.0000 1.0000 -0.3000 4.7089 1.0000 0.0000
 5 5 90.7003 0.0000 0.0000 -0.1661 -0.2000 0.0000 16.0000 0.2578
 3.0618 -0.2000 15.0000 1.0000 -0.0914 5.4665 0.0000 0.0000
 6 ! Nr of off-diagonal terms; Ediss;Ro;gamma;rsigma;rpi;rpi2
 1 2 0.1239 1.4004 9.8467 1.1210 -1.0000 -1.0000
 1 3 0.1156 1.8520 9.8317 1.2854 1.1352 1.0706
 2 3 0.0283 1.2885 10.9190 0.9215 -1.0000 -1.0000
 1 5 0.1169 2.3000 9.2890 1.6264 -1.0000 -1.0000
 2 5 0.1445 1.1103 13.0000 1.5714 -1.0000 -1.0000
 3 5 0.2237 1.6610 10.6568 1.7139 -1.0000 -1.0000
 36 ! Nr of angles;at1;at2;at3;Thetao,o;ka;kb;pv1;pv2
 1 1 1 59.0573 30.7029 0.7606 0.0000 0.7180 6.2933 1.1244
 1 1 2 65.7758 14.5234 6.2481 0.0000 0.5665 0.0000 1.6255
 2 1 2 70.2607 25.2202 3.7312 0.0000 0.0050 0.0000 2.7500
 1 2 2 0.0000 0.0000 6.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 1.0400
 1 2 1 0.0000 3.4110 7.7350 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 1.0400
 2 2 2 0.0000 27.9213 5.8635 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 1.0400
 1 1 3 49.6811 7.1713 4.3889 0.0000 0.7171 10.2661 1.0463
 3 1 3 77.7473 40.1718 2.9802 -25.3063 1.6170 -46.1315 2.2503
 2 1 3 65.0000 13.8815 5.0583 0.0000 0.4985 0.0000 1.4900
 1 3 1 73.5312 44.7275 0.7354 0.0000 3.0000 0.0000 1.0684
 1 3 3 79.4761 36.3701 1.8943 0.0000 0.7351 67.6777 3.0000
 3 3 3 80.7324 30.4554 0.9953 0.0000 1.6310 50.0000 1.0783
 1 3 2 70.1880 20.9562 0.3864 0.0000 0.0050 0.0000 1.6924
 2 3 3 75.6935 50.0000 2.0000 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000 1.1680
 2 3 2 85.8000 9.8453 2.2720 0.0000 2.8635 0.0000 1.5800
 1 2 3 0.0000 25.0000 3.0000 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000 1.0400
 3 2 3 0.0000 15.0000 2.8900 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 2.8774
 2 2 3 0.0000 8.5744 3.0000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 1.0421
 5 3 5 53.8540 30.0000 2.0649 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000 1.7008
 3 5 5 55.7429 4.8907 3.9242 0.0000 0.1000 0.0000 1.0000
 3 3 5 90.0000 30.0000 1.6813 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000 1.9155
 3 5 3 0.0100 30.0000 8.0000 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000 2.4156
 2 5 2 25.6680 10.1984 7.6844 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000 1.2474
 2 2 5 83.9156 13.0474 0.9983 0.0000 1.0001 0.0000 3.1381
 5 2 5 0.9367 12.0943 6.6344 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000 1.0115
 2 5 5 40.0354 9.2882 8.0000 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000 2.7288 
 1 1 5 23.3470 30.0000 4.9485 0.0000 0.1000 0.0000 2.6345
 3 1 5 0.0100 30.0000 7.8334 0.0000 0.1000 0.0000 1.1134
 1 5 5 81.4675 17.7241 8.0000 0.0000 0.1000 0.0000 3.3824
 1 5 1 76.1959 30.0000 8.0000 0.0000 0.1000 0.0000 1.3967
 5 1 5 0.0100 30.0000 7.8334 0.0000 0.1000 0.0000 1.1134
 2 1 5 81.2014 30.0000 0.5384 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000 1.9241
 1 5 2 90.0000 0.2503 0.0100 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000 2.1438
 1 2 5 6.0617 0.0100 7.5704 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000 3.9408
 2 3 5 50.4877 0.1082 1.9877 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000 1.3192
 2 5 3 17.8836 0.0100 1.7426 0.5000 1.0000 0.0000 1.1872
 25 ! Nr of torsions;at1;at2;at3;at4;;V1;V2;V3;V2(BO);vconj;n.u;n
 1 1 1 1 -0.2500 34.7453 0.0288 -6.3507 -1.6000 0.0000 0.0000
 1 1 1 2 -0.2500 29.2131 0.2945 -4.9581 -2.1802 0.0000 0.0000
 2 1 1 2 -0.2500 31.2081 0.4539 -4.8923 -2.2677 0.0000 0.0000
 1 1 1 3 -0.3495 22.2142 -0.2959 -2.5000 -1.9066 0.0000 0.0000
 2 1 1 3 0.0646 24.3195 0.6259 -3.9603 -1.0000 0.0000 0.0000
 3 1 1 3 -0.5456 5.5756 0.8433 -5.1924 -1.0180 0.0000 0.0000
 1 1 3 1 1.7555 27.9267 0.0072 -2.6533 -1.0000 0.0000 0.0000
 1 1 3 2 -1.4358 36.7830 -1.0000 -8.1821 -1.0000 0.0000 0.0000
 2 1 3 1 -1.3959 34.5053 0.7200 -2.5714 -2.1641 0.0000 0.0000
 2 1 3 2 -2.5000 70.0597 1.0000 -3.5539 -2.9929 0.0000 0.0000
 1 1 3 3 0.6852 11.2819 -0.4784 -2.5000 -2.1085 0.0000 0.0000
 2 1 3 3 0.1933 80.0000 1.0000 -4.0590 -3.0000 0.0000 0.0000
 3 1 3 1 -1.9889 76.4820 -0.1796 -3.8301 -3.0000 0.0000 0.0000
 3 1 3 2 0.2160 72.7707 -0.7087 -4.2100 -3.0000 0.0000 0.0000
 3 1 3 3 -2.5000 71.0772 0.2542 -3.1631 -3.0000 0.0000 0.0000
 1 3 3 1 2.5000 -0.6002 1.0000 -3.4297 -2.8858 0.0000 0.0000
 1 3 3 2 -2.5000 -3.3822 0.7004 -5.4467 -2.9586 0.0000 0.0000
 2 3 3 2 2.5000 -4.0000 0.9000 -2.5000 -1.0000 0.0000 0.0000
 1 3 3 3 1.2329 -4.0000 1.0000 -2.5000 -1.7479 0.0000 0.0000
 2 3 3 3 0.8302 -4.0000 -0.7763 -2.5000 -1.0000 0.0000 0.0000
 3 3 3 3 -2.5000 -4.0000 1.0000 -2.5000 -1.0000 0.0000 0.0000 
 5 3 3 5 1.7276 50.0000 0.0100 -2.5000 -1.0000 0.0000 0.0000
 1 1 1 5 2.1746 45.0000 0.6721 -2.5000 0.0000 0.0000 0.0000
 5 1 1 5 5.5647 24.5181 8.0000 -2.5173 0.0000 0.0000 1.1091
 2 1 1 5 0.0100 11.4523 2.1450 -3.5000 0.0000 0.0000 1.0000
 1 ! Nr of hydrogen bonds;at1;at2;at3;Rhb;Dehb;vhb1
 3 2 3 2.1200 -3.5800 1.4500 19.5000
```

**CODE FFIELD 2** :

```
# Co-Li-O
rc = 4.8
delr = 0.1
augt1 = 0
erose_form = 2
ialloy = 2
# Co-Co
zbl(1,1) = 0
nn2(1,1) = 1
rho0(1) =     0.5000
Ec(1,1) =     1.6500
re(1,1) =     3.0200
alpha(1,1) =  3.09825956
repuls(1,1) =     0.0500
attrac(1,1) =     0.0500
Cmin(1,1,1) =     0.1600
Cmax(1,1,1) =     2.8000
# Li-Li
zbl(2,2) = 0
nn2(2,2) = 1
rho0(2) =     1.0000
Ec(2,2) =     4.4100
re(2,2) =     2.5000
alpha(2,2) =  5.23561475
repuls(2,2) =     0.0000
attrac(2,2) =     0.0000
Cmin(2,2,2) =     0.4900
Cmax(2,2,2) =     2.0000
# O-O
zbl(3,3) = 0
nn2(3,3) = 1
rho0(3) =    12.0000
Ec(3,3) =     2.5600
re(3,3) =     1.2100
alpha(3,3) =  6.88000000
repuls(3,3) =     0.0000
attrac(3,3) =     0.0000
Cmin(3,3,3) =     2.0000
Cmax(3,3,3) =     2.8000
# Co-Li
zbl(1,2) = 0
nn2(1,2) = 1
lattce(1,2) = 'b1'
Ec(1,2) =     2.1178
re(1,2) =     2.3134
alpha(1,2) =  3.97495801
repuls(1,2) =     0.0000
attrac(1,2) =     0.0000
Cmin(1,1,2) =     1.8000
Cmin(2,2,1) =     0.1600
Cmin(1,2,1) =     0.3000
Cmin(2,1,1) =     0.3000
Cmin(1,2,2) =     0.3000
Cmin(2,1,2) =     0.3000
Cmax(1,1,2) =     3.6000
Cmax(2,2,1) =     2.8000
Cmax(1,2,1) =     2.8000
Cmax(2,1,1) =     2.8000
Cmax(1,2,2) =     2.8000
Cmax(2,1,2) =     2.8000
# Co-O
zbl(1,3) = 0
nn2(1,3) = 1
lattce(1,3) = 'b1'
Ec(1,3) =     1.6836
re(1,3) =     1.9500
alpha(1,3) =  7.31510556
repuls(1,3) =     0.0700
attrac(1,3) =     0.0700
Cmin(1,1,3) =     1.0000
Cmin(3,3,1) =     0.3000
Cmin(1,3,1) =     0.7000
Cmin(3,1,1) =     0.7000
Cmin(1,3,3) =     0.6000
Cmin(3,1,3) =     0.6000
Cmax(1,1,3) =     1.5500
Cmax(3,3,1) =     1.5500
Cmax(1,3,1) =     1.3500
Cmax(3,1,1) =     1.3500
Cmax(1,3,3) =     2.1500
Cmax(3,1,3) =     2.1500
# Li-O
zbl(2,3) = 0
nn2(2,3) = 1
lattce(2,3) = 'b1'
Ec(2,3) =     1.7917
re(2,3) =     2.0785
alpha(2,3) =  6.10015156
repuls(2,3) =     0.0200
attrac(2,3) =     0.0000
Cmin(2,2,3) =     4.0000
Cmin(3,3,2) =     0.1000
Cmin(2,3,2) =     0.5000
Cmin(3,2,2) =     0.5000
Cmin(2,3,3) =     0.5000
Cmin(3,2,3) =     0.5000
Cmax(2,2,3) =     5.0000
Cmax(3,3,2) =     1.8000
Cmax(2,3,2) =     4.0000
Cmax(3,2,2) =     4.0000
Cmax(2,3,3) =     4.0000
Cmax(3,2,3) =     4.0000
# Co-Li-O
Cmin(1,2,3) =     1.2000
Cmin(2,1,3) =     1.2000
Cmin(1,3,2) =     4.0000
Cmin(3,1,2) =     4.0000
Cmin(2,3,1) =     2.5000
Cmin(3,2,1) =     2.5000
Cmax(1,2,3) =     4.1000
Cmax(2,1,3) =     4.1000
Cmax(1,3,2) =     6.0000
Cmax(3,1,2) =     6.0000
Cmax(2,3,1) =     5.0000
Cmax(3,2,1) =     5.0000
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: +1 and welcome to our new community here! I recall that you [asked this on the LAMMPS Facebook group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/lammps/posts/1912314562308152/) and that I suggested for you to ask it here, so thanks for eventually signing up! Could you please copy and paste your input file and your error message in a `code` block rather than trying to send us a screenshot? We don't really accept screenshots of code here anymore.

Comment: Please put the input file in a `code` block, not a comment.

Comment: I have few doubt,  In script you have mentioned two reax force field but you have given meam force field as CODE FFIELD 2 : . Second doubt is you defined pair_coeff 1 2 ffield_Pd_O_C_H.ajust.reax.txt Pd O NULL    WHY NULL

Comment: I tested soo many things, in the final code I put in the the two of "PAIR_COEFF  *  *"

Comment: Millie, it's possible that @Pranavkumar didn't see your reply because you didn't ping him. Pranav, was the most recent comment helpful at all? Since MIllie hasn't signed in since 8 months ago, and the question was written 8 months ago, I've voted to close the question as "abandoned", but if you have enough information to answer it, please do!

Comment: @NikeDattani it is difficult to answer. Kindly close it.